# Mongoose findOne queries for undefined values (not existent in database). I am using MERN to do an instagram clone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am trying to do a register for an instagram clone. You can register with username and email OR username and mobile.

When the user1 uses username and email, the mobile will be undefined in the database (not existent).

After adding the user1, I try to add the user2 using username and email as well. The mongoose findOne function queries for the undefined mobile of the user1 because user2 has undefined mobile as well. So, it says that the mobile is already in use..

user1.mobile = undefined AND user2.mobile = undefined as well, so it responds "Mobile already in use" message

I am trying to find a way to avoid for the query to find undefined or unexistent values or another way to solve my problem.

```
export const register = (req, res) => {
    const newUserData = req.body;
    User.findOne({ $or: [{ username: newUserData.username }, { email: newUserData.email }, { mobile: newUserData.mobile }] })
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                if (user.username === newUserData.username)
                    res.status(400).json({ message: { messageBody: "Username already in use", messageError: true } });
                else if (user.email === newUserData.email)
                    res.status(400).json(..."Email already in use"...);
                else if (user.mobile === newUserData.mobile)
                    res.status(400).json(..."Mobile already in use"...);
            }
            else {
                const newUser = new User(newUserData);
                newUser.save()
                    .then(user => {
                        res.status(201).json(..."Account succesfully created"...);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).json(..."Error has occured (saving user)"...);
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json(..."Error has occured (checking if user exists)"...);
        })
```

I am almost sure that the problem is because findOne finds a document that also has undefined mobile or undefined email even though the documents have nothing similar.

**I could fix it..**

I changed the Schema and set a default value for the email and mobile. So, if a user registers with username and email (no mobile), user.mobile will be undefined and there will not be undefined values for mobile field in the database because they will be all defaulted to something.

Cons: Cannot have default value plus unique, so had to make them not unique. Even though, The _id is still the primary key, and the username is also unique. Also, had to erase the whole database and start over.

PD: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the values ***exist and*** match with the supplied values.

```js
if (user.username && user.username === newUserData.username)
    res.status(400).json({ message: { messageBody: "Username already in use", messageError: true } });
else if (user.email user.email === newUserData.email)
    res.status(400).json(..."Email already in use"...);
else if (user.mobile && user.mobile === newUserData.mobile)
    res.status(400).json(..."Mobile already in use"...);
```

Comment: I am trying, postman post is sending the request and does not gets any response. I think is because it does not run any if statement